# How to always update date in json file, which you take from website for telegram bot? python telegram bot

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot

I guess it's trivial question but I couldn't find the answer.
I took information from website and convert it to json file. Then I add this json file to telegram bot(python). How can I always update the information of json file?

python

```
elif message.text == 'Currency':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item_1 = types.KeyboardButton('EUR')
        item_2 = types.KeyboardButton('USD')
        item_3 = types.KeyboardButton('Back')
        markup.add(item_1, item_2, item_3)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Choose', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == 'USD' or message.text == 'EUR':
        with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f: 
            data = json.loads(f.read()) 
            for i in data['Exchange_rates']:
                if message.text =='USD' and  i['currency'] == 'USD':
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, (i['currency'] + '\n' + i['price']))
                elif message.text =='EUR' and i['currency'] == 'EUR':
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, (i['currency'] + '\n' + i['price']))
```

json file

```
{
 "Exchange_rates": [
  {
   "currency": "AUD",
   "price": "41,8082",
   "currency_full": "Австралийский доллар",
   "amount": "1"
  },
  {
   "currency": "AZN",
   "price": "36,0391",
   "currency_full": "Азербайджанский манат",
   "amount": "1"
  },
  {
   "currency": "AMD",
   "price": "14,9186",
   "currency_full": "Армянских драмов",
   "amount": "100"
  },
  {
   "currency": "BYN",
   "price": "22,6309",
   "currency_full": "Белорусский рубль",
   "amount": "1"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to update the JSON file from the Bot (User input)? Or an API fetch?

Comment: API fetch I guess

Comment: You can set the function in another file with an infinite loop + delay. Or use the schedule library to schedule the function to run every now and then in the same file.

Comment: Thanks. I think it'll work